# LDAP filter - retrieve all users in a given group

Tags: ldap, ldap-client

I have a problem with a filter in LDAP. I want to retrieve all the users in a specified LDAP group.
The LDIF is like this one:

```
dn: cn=engineering,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: engineering
member: uid=alex,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
member: uid=amy,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
...

dn: uid=alex,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Alex Ander
gidNumber: 5000
homeDirectory: /home/alex
...
```

I've tried

```
(&(objectClass=user)
  (memberof=cn=engineering,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve  all the members of the group, use the following parameters in a search request:

- base object: `cn=engineering,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com`
- scope: base
- filter: `(&)`
- requested attributes: `member`

The response from the server (assuming the authorization state of the connection on which the search request is processed permits) will be a list of all the `member` attribute values in that group.

If the LDAP client requires the full entry of each of the members, then transmit a search search request for each member. The client has the DN, so only a base level scope is required, and list each attribute to be retrieved.

Alternatively:

- base object: `ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com`
- scope: one (if all objects are one level below `ou=users`)
- filter: `(&(objectClass=inetorgPerson)(memberOf=cn=engineering,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com))`
- requested attributes, for example, `cn, homeDirectory`

The response from the (assuming the authorization state of the connection on which the search request is processed permits) will be a list of `inetOrgPerson` members that otherwise match the search parameters, such as being a member of that group.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thank you Terry, but the memberOf is not present on my LDAP server.
I saw this article http://blog.oddbit.com/post/generating-a-memberof-attribute-for-posixgroups and the problem is that I can't add additional attributes. One person suggests me to to the first query to find all the UIDs and then create the string appending every usernames like (& (ou=Users) (| (uid=user1)(uid=user2) ... (uid=userN) ) ).
This is VERY ugly but it seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Sadly Mr Gardner's site is no longer hosting this content,.